# How to do MIPS about .asciiz

Tags: mips

I have a question, I'm writing a program that could output a string base on the user-input string.

For example,

user inputs>> Bear

outputs>> It's a mammal.

or

user inputs>> Snake

outputs>> It's a reptile.

I'm only gonna do 3 animals(easy). "Bear, Snake, Pigeon" So any other animals are invalid. And if the user inputs one of those 3 animals given the outputs should be either mammal, reptile, or bird.

I've written the data code this is not the whole code

.data

mammal: .asciiz "It's a mammal"

bird: .asciiz "It's a bird"

reptile: .asciiz "It's a reptile"

invalid: .asciiz "invalid"

check: .asciiz "bear\n"

So my question is can you store multiple strings on check like this?

check: .asciiz "bear\n","snake\n","pigeon\n" <- I don't know if you can do this.

Is there a correct way to do this?
I want to store multiple strings on check so I can check if it's one of the animals inputted and then make the corresponding output.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a list/array of animals. There isn't a single correct way to store it, just use whatever is easiest for you. Could be an array of pointers to the data strings (null terminated so you know you're at the end) or a single string with newline separated mammal names (with a 0 byte at the end to know you reached the end).